# Prove there's a monochromatic isosceles triangle.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle, coloring

The points in a circle are coloured red and blue. Prove that there exists a monochromatic isoceles triangle.

I can prove that there exists a monochromatic triangle. If there are no three points of the same colour, then all the remaining points are of the other colour.

I have tried to select a point and then draw a line passing through the centre of the circle and the selected point. Now the circle is divided into two semicircles. I call two points mirrors if they lie on different semi circles and have the same distance from the selected point. I have tried to arrive at a contradiction in assuming that there are no mirror points with the same colour as the selected point but it's not successful.

Comment: A picture might help. I am not sure whether I understand the exercise correct. You want to show the existence of three points with the same colour within a circle forming an isoscle triangle, no matter, how the (inifinite many) points are colored, right ?

Comment: @Peter Yes, that is correct. I don't know how to describe pictures in $Latex$.

Comment: I mixed isoscles with equilateral. No wonder I did not find a solution.

Comment: @Peter Can you tell me how pictures are added in LaTeX though ?

Comment: No, unfortunately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inscribe a regular pentagon in the circle.  Three of the vertices must have the same color and they form the triangle you seek.

Comment: Well done, Lulu

Comment: I am doing a lot of self study and practising proof writing. I collect elegant problems and proofs for myself. But, I don't have anybody to check it. As I was writing this proof, I was wondering how much is necessary to conclude it. Is this much sufficient or should I also write down why an isosceles triangle is formed ? (You don't have to write that in the proof. I can do that myself. I'm just wondering how much is necessary to complete the proof.)

Comment: Well, I'd say it was worth a line or two to argue that any three vertices of a regular pentagon make an isosceles triangle.

Comment: Ok. So, in the proof I wrote I said there are two cases - Either one of the three shares an edge with both the others, or two of them are and edge $CD$ and the third is not adjacent to either. In the first case, the two sides are equal. In the second, $AC = AD$ because triangles $ABC$ and $AED$ are congruent. Is this satisfactory ? Or should I even prove congruence ?

Comment: I'd say that was enough...

Comment: Thanks for your guidance. Are you a professional mathematician ?

Comment: Retired, but yes.

Comment: So, is my proof sufficient now ? I appreciate your help

Comment: I would say it was sufficient, yes.  By the way, if you want a more combinatorial style proof:  it is easy to see that I can find points two points $P,Q$ on the circle which have the same color  (Blue, say) and which are extremely close to each other.  Let $X, Y$ on the circle be such that the four points $X,P,Q,Y$ are equi-spaced and let $M$ be the midpoint of arc $PQ$.  If $M$ is Blue, then $\Delta PMQ$ works.  If $X$ is Blue then $\Delta XPQ$ works.  If $Y$ is Blue then $\Delta PQY$ works.  If $X,M,Y$ are all Red then $\Delta XMY$ works.

Comment: What do you mean by extremely close to each other ?@lulu

Comment: Literally....as close as you desire. (take an arc of length $\epsilon>0$.  It contains uncountably many points, so you can find three of the same color).  Not terribly important for your problem, though when I add in the points $X,Y$ I need to ensure that they don't coincide and that $X,PQ,Y$ appear in order.  That gets messed up if $P,Q$ are (say) the endpoints of a diameter.

Comment: After I posted the pentagon argument, I asked myself if I could make the isosceles triangle as small (by area) as I wanted.  The second argument proves that I can.  On the other side, there is an upper bound on the area.  For example, you can not guarantee a monochromatic equilateral triangle.  I did not search for the largest guaranteed monochromatic isosceles, though it might be interesting to discover it.

Comment: Correction:  in my second to last comment, I meant to say only that I could guarantee finding two points (my $P,Q$) of the same color in the tiny arc.  Of course, I can find infinitely many of the same color in that arc, but the argument only requires two.